# Parsing json string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What i need to do here is whenever i call a method say for campaign data it needs to go to "name" : "campaign " and give me "values" in this format

`{"car":"car", 
"bus":"bus",
"truck":"truck",
"train":"train"}`

in the same way i need for sub campaign . (Comment if anything is unclear)

```
{
"fields": [
        {
        "name": "campaign",
        "default": "",
        "values": [
            "car",
            "bus",
            "truck",
            "train"
        ]
    },

   {
        "name": "subCampaign", 
        "default": "",
        "values": [
            "Spring 2015",
            "BTS 2015",
            "BTS 2014",
            "Holiday 2015",
            "Holiday 2014"   
        ]
    },
]
}
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working here. We are not "free code service". You should show us what have you tried so far and what exactly is not working in your solution - in that case we could probably help you. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Do you need an array or an object.

Comment: _give me "values" in form of array like {"car":"car", "bus":"bus","truck":"truck","train":"train"}_ `this is not array, this is an objec`

Comment: Are you sure you're even dealing with JSON? The question is **very** unclear. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry guys, I was in a bit of hurry...Apologies.. !!

Answer (score 3):

If we have

```
var obj ={
"fields": [
        {
        "name": "campaign",
        "default": "",
        "values": [
            "car",
            "bus",
            "truck",
            "train"
        ]
    },

   {
        "name": "subCampaign", 
        "default": "",
        "values": [
            "Spring 2015",
            "BTS 2015",
            "BTS 2014",
            "Holiday 2015",
            "Holiday 2014"   
        ]
    },
]
};
```

You can do it like this, say for `campaign, you can use:

```
var result = {}; 
obj.fields[0].values.forEach(function(val){ 
  result[val] = val
});
```

This would give `result` as object having value : `{car: "car", bus: "bus", truck: "truck", train: "train"}`

Comment: Do upvote and aceppt if working. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want `{"car":"car", "bus":"bus","truck":"truck","train":"train"}`

```js
var object = {
    "fields": [{
        "name": "campaign",
            "default": "",
            "values": [
            "car",
            "bus",
            "truck",
            "train"]
    },

    {
        "name": "subCampaign",
            "default": "",
            "values": [
            "Spring 2015",
            "BTS 2015",
            "BTS 2014",
            "Holiday 2015",
            "Holiday 2014"]
    }, ]
};
var passingObj = object.fields[0].values;
alert(JSON.stringify(getObj(passingObj)));

function getObj(passingObj) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var index in passingObj) {
        obj[passingObj[index]] = passingObj[index];
    }
    return obj;

}
```